# cheap BGA x-ray machine?

Tags: jtag

I want to look under a BGA chip and map JTAG pins to traces where I can attach a JTAGulator. Is there some version of a BGA x-ray that isn't thousands of $'s?

Here's a picture of the BGA's. Would it be easier to build a breakout connector to insert between this and main board?

[image]

If I desoldered them, maybe I could stick them in a socket and read them directly?

Comment: Desolder the chip. It's only expensive if you mess it up.

Comment: I used to do a lot of swapping BGA's, what is a good hot air station nowadays for this?

Comment: Not sure what type of chips those are; I didn't find anything searching but it's likely I misread the numbers. I'm guessing RAM since there's two of them? But I could be wrong. If they were eMMC, there are sockets you can buy to read them, or breakout the pins manually to a dummy card. Not sure, there are some fairly cheap kits online that seem alright.

Comment: The PCB stencil says Flash Board. The top number is 3000P0ZBQ0, the second row number is A5537314 and row 3 is Z5532077A. I couldn't find an exact datasheet, though I found one "sorta" similar for a NumonyxTM StrataFlash Embedded Memory (P30), don't know if Intel would collaborate with them? I was thinking about an infrared oven to pull them, vs. a hot air station.